# Merge the duplicate rows on multiple column?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, data-manipulation

Sample Input:

```
DID        FIRST NAME  MIDDLE NAME  LAST NAME  STREET  CITY  STATE  ZIP    DOB        PIN                TIN
CRA0012347129   John JR       Nan      Doe      Nan     Nan   Nan 1124.0 02-07-2020 12345678998765432 268869162.0
CRA0012347152   John          Nan      Doe      Nan     Nan   Nan  201.0 12-12-2020 12261986          Nan
CRA0012347286   John          Nan      Doe      Nan     Nan   Nan   Nan Nan 12261986      268869162.0
```

Instructions:
1 You have to merge duplicate records (rows) using PIN and TIN columns as primary keys. Example given below.
2 You can use DOB column as secondary key. Think of concatenating this column with other columns to create a secondary key.
3 Ensure all 'similar' records (rows) are merged based on the above two points.

Expected Output:

```
DID                                          FIRST NAME      MIDDLE NAME LAST NAME STREET CITY  STATE  ZIP         
CRA0012347129, CRA0012347152, CRA0012347286  John JR, John       NaN        Doe     NaN    NaN   NaN   1124, 201   

 DOB                          PIN                        TIN
02/07/2020, 12/12/2020  12345678998765432,'012261986  '268869162
```

Comment: How exactly are you planning to merge since your primary keys PIN and TIN have no intersection between rows?

Comment: I have to merge unique values of other columns based on common  TIN or PIN column.